# Won't let me set class name of a Javascript created div

Tags: javascript

I'm using a function to create a div element on the page. I want to assign a className but I get the error: cannot set property className of undefined.

But I did this in another function and it worked. Why is this one not working?

If I failed to provide the code relevant to the problem I apologize. I'm in a rush and included code that I thought might be relevant in order of relevancy.

** WORKING FUNCTION **

```
function makeBomb() {
    if (player.ready && (player.hasBomb < player.maxBombs)) {
        player.score -= 300;
        player.hasBomb++;
        player.bomb = document.createElement('div');
        player.bomb.className = 'bomb'; //DOESN'T THROW ERROR ----
        gameArea.appendChild(player.bomb);
        player.bomb.x = player.x;
        player.bomb.y = player.y;
        player.bomb.style.left = player.bomb.x + 'px';
        player.bomb.style.top = player.bomb.y + 'px';
        player.ready = false;
        setTimeout(function () {
            player.ready = true;
        }, 1000);
    }
 }
```

** NOT WORKING FUNCTION **

```
function makeBullet() {
    if (player.enemy.bulletCount < player.enemy.maxBulletCount && 
player.enemy.bulletInterval == true)

    player.enemy.bullet = document.createElement('div');
    player.enemy.bullet.className = 'bullet';  //THROWS ERROR -----
    gameArea.appendChild(player.enemy.bullet);
    player.enemy.bullet.x = player.enemy.x;
    player.enemy.bullet.y = player.enemy.y;
    player.enemy.bullet.style.left = player.enemy.bullet.x + 
(player.enemy.offsetWidth / 3) + 'px';
    player.enemy.bullet.style.top = player.enemy.bullet.y + 
(player.enemy.offsetHeight / 4) + 'px';
    player.enemy.bulletCount++;
    player.enemy.bulletInterval = false;
    setInterval(function(){
        player.enemy.bulletInterval = true;
    }, 4000);
}
```

** STARTING CODE THAT MIGHT HAVE CONTEXT IDK**

```
function start() {
    if (player.games === 1) {
        gameArea.removeChild(finalScore);
    }
    gameMessage.style.display = 'none';
    score.style.display = "inline-block";
    scoreArea.style.display = "inline-block";
    text.style.display = "inline-block";
    player.inplay = true;
    makeEnemy();
    player.plane = document.createElement("div");
    player.plane.setAttribute("class", "plane");

    gameArea.appendChild(player.plane);

    player.enemy.x = player.enemy.offsetLeft;

    player.enemy.y = player.enemy.offsetTop;

    player.x = player.plane.offsetLeft;

    player.y = player.plane.offsetTop;


    window.requestAnimationFrame(playGame);


}
```

** OTHER CODE THAT MIGHT HAVE CONTEXT **

```
function makeEnemy() {

    player.enemy = document.createElement('div');
    player.enemy.className = 'enemy';
    player.enemy.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * . 
   gameArea.offsetWidth - 300) + 100 + 'px';


    gameArea.appendChild(player.enemy);
    player.enemy.x = player.enemy.offsetLeft;

}
```

** JUST IN CASE YOU NEED -- idk its hard for me to keep track of everything that might be related to the problem... sorry.. **

```
title.addEventListener("click", changeColor);

const gameArea = document.querySelector(".gameArea");
const game = document.querySelector(".game");
const scoreArea = document.querySelector(".scoreArea");
const score = document.querySelector(".score");
const text = document.querySelector(".text");


document.addEventListener('keydown', pressOn);
document.addEventListener('keyup', pressOff);
gameMessage.addEventListener('click', start);

let player = {
    score: 2000,
    speed: 5,
    inplay: false,
    ready: true,
    maxBombs: 4,
    hasBomb: 0,
    hit: 0,
   hitMax: 9,
   games: 0,
    enemy: {
        x: 0
    },
    getHit: 0,
    getHitMax: 20,
    swing: false

}

let keys = {
   space: false
}
```

** FULL JS FILE: BE WARNED IM VERY NEW AND THIS IS NOT GOOD CODE **

```
const title = document.querySelector(".title");
const gameMessage = document.querySelector(".gameMessage");


function changeColor() {
    let newArray = ["darksalmon", "lightsalmon", "crimson", "red", "deeppink", "yellowgreen", "ghostwhite"];
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(newArray.length - 1));
    if (title.style.color != newArray[random]) {
        title.style.color = newArray[random];
        console.log(title.style.color);
    } else {
        changeColor();
    }
}


title.addEventListener("click", changeColor);

const gameArea = document.querySelector(".gameArea");
const game = document.querySelector(".game");
const scoreArea = document.querySelector(".scoreArea");
const score = document.querySelector(".score");
const text = document.querySelector(".text");


document.addEventListener('keydown', pressOn);
document.addEventListener('keyup', pressOff);
gameMessage.addEventListener('click', start);

let player = {
    score: 2000,
    speed: 5,
    inplay: false,
    ready: true,
    maxBombs: 4,
    hasBomb: 0,
    hit: 0,
    hitMax: 9,
    games: 0,
    enemy: {
        x: 0
    },
    getHit: 0,
    getHitMax: 20,
    swing: false

}

let keys = {
    space: false
}

function start() {
    if (player.games === 1) {
        gameArea.removeChild(finalScore);
    }
    gameMessage.style.display = 'none';
    score.style.display = "inline-block";
    scoreArea.style.display = "inline-block";
    text.style.display = "inline-block";
    player.inplay = true;
    makeEnemy();
    player.plane = document.createElement("div");
    player.plane.setAttribute("class", "plane");

    gameArea.appendChild(player.plane);

    player.enemy.x = player.enemy.offsetLeft;

    player.enemy.y = player.enemy.offsetTop;

    player.x = player.plane.offsetLeft;

    player.y = player.plane.offsetTop;


    window.requestAnimationFrame(playGame);


}



function playGame() {
    if (player.inplay) {
        moveBomb();

        if(player.x < (gameArea.offsetWidth / 2)) {
            console.log('WORKED');
            makeBullet();
        }

        if (player.swing){
                 player.plane.style.backgroundImage ='url(guts1.png)';
                 player.swing = false;
                 //player.plane.style.width = 210 + 'px';

                }


        if (keys['x'] && player.enemy && isCollide(player.plane, player.enemy)) {
                removeEnemy();
            }



        if (player.enemy) {


            if (isCollide(player.plane, player.enemy)) {


                player.getHit++;
                if (player.getHit > player.getHitMax){
                    endGame();
                }    
            } else {
                player.getHit = 0;
            }
            if (player.x > player.enemy.x) {
                player.enemy.x += 1;
            }
            if (player.x < player.enemy.x) {
                player.enemy.x -= 1;
            }
            player.enemy.style.left = player.enemy.x + 'px';
        }

        if (player.hasBomb >= player.maxBombs && player.bomb.y > gameArea.offsetHeight - 20) {

            endGame();
        }
        if (keys.space) {
            makeBomb()

        }
        if (keys.ArrowUp && player.y > 0) {
            player.y -= (player.speed + (player.speed * .5));
        }
        if (keys.ArrowDown && player.y < (gameArea.offsetHeight - player.plane.offsetHeight - 30)) {
            player.y += (player.speed + (player.speed * .5));
        }
        if (keys.ArrowLeft && player.x > 0) {
            player.x -= (player.speed + (player.speed * .5));
        }
        if (keys.ArrowRight && player.x < (gameArea.offsetWidth)) {
            player.x += (player.speed - (player.speed * .5));
        }

        if (player.x == (gameArea.offsetWidth)) {
            player.x = 0;
            player.score -= 100;
            if (!player.enemy) {
                makeEnemy();
            }
        }

        player.score -= .4;

        if (player.score < 0) {
            player.score = 0;
        }

        player.x += (player.speed * .5);


        score.innerHTML = Math.floor(player.score) + ' Bombs left: ' + (player.maxBombs - player.hasBomb);



        player.plane.style.left = player.x + 'px';
        player.plane.style.top = player.y + 'px';

        window.requestAnimationFrame(playGame);
    }
}

function pressOn(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let tempKey = (e.key == " ") ? "space" : e.key;
    keys[tempKey] = true;

        if (keys['x'] && player.swing == false){
                 playerPlane = player.plane;
                 player.plane.style.backgroundImage ='url(guts2.png)';
                 setTimeout(function () {
                 player.swing = true;
                 }, 300);
                 //player.plane.style.width = 400 + 'px';
                }
    console.log(tempKey)
    console.log(keys);

}

function pressOff(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let tempKey = (e.key== " ") ? "space" : e.key;
    console.log(tempKey);

//    if (keys['x'] && player.swing){
//               playerPlane = player.plane;
//               player.plane.style.backgroundImage ='url(guts1.png)';
//                 player.swing = false;
//                 //player.plane.style.width = 210 + 'px';
//              
//              }

    if (keys['space'] || keys['x']) {
    keys['space'] = 0;
    keys['x'] = 0;
    }
    keys[tempKey] = false;
    console.log(keys);
}

function moveBomb() {
    let bombs = document.querySelectorAll('.bomb');
    bombs.forEach(function (item) {
        item.y += 10;
        item.style.top = item.y + 'px';
        if (item.y > gameArea.offsetHeight) {
            item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
            player.bomb = null;
        }
        if (player.enemy && player.bomb) {
            if (isCollide(item, player.enemy)) {
               player.hit++;

            }

        }

        if (player.hit > player.hitMax) {
            item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
            player.bomb = null;
            player.score += 2000;
            player.hit = 0;
            player.hasBomb -= 2
            gameArea.removeChild(player.enemy);
            player.enemy = null;
        }
    })
}

function makeEnemy() {

    player.enemy = document.createElement('div');
    player.enemy.className = 'enemy';
    player.enemy.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * gameArea.offsetWidth - 300) + 100 + 'px';


    gameArea.appendChild(player.enemy);
    player.enemy.x = player.enemy.offsetLeft;

}

//function getLocationX(a){
//    let aRect = a.getBoundingClientRect();
//    let aX = aRect.x;
//    return aX;
//   //w console.log(aX);
//}
//
//function getLocationY(a){
//    let aRect = a.getBoundingClientRect();
//    let aY = aRect.y;
//    return aY;
//   // console.log(aY);
//}

function isCollide(a, b) {
    let aRect = a.getBoundingClientRect();
    let bRect = b.getBoundingClientRect();
    return !(
        (aRect.bottom < bRect.top) ||
        (aRect.top > bRect.bottom) ||
        (aRect.right < bRect.left) ||
        (aRect.left > bRect.right)
    )
}

function makeBomb() {
    if (player.ready && (player.hasBomb < player.maxBombs)) {
        player.score -= 300;
        player.hasBomb++;
        player.bomb = document.createElement('div');
        player.bomb.className = 'bomb';
        gameArea.appendChild(player.bomb);
        player.bomb.x = player.x;
        player.bomb.y = player.y;
        player.bomb.style.left = player.bomb.x + 'px';
        player.bomb.style.top = player.bomb.y + 'px';
        player.ready = false;
        setTimeout(function () {
            player.ready = true;
        }, 1000);
    }
}


function makeBullet() {
    if (player.enemy.bulletCount < player.enemy.maxBulletCount && player.enemy.bulletInterval == true)

    player.enemy.bullet = document.createElement('div');
    player.enemy.bullet.className = 'bullet';
    gameArea.appendChild(player.enemy.bullet);
    player.enemy.bullet.x = player.enemy.x;
    player.enemy.bullet.y = player.enemy.y;
    player.enemy.bullet.style.left = player.enemy.bullet.x + (player.enemy.offsetWidth / 3) + 'px';
    player.enemy.bullet.style.top = player.enemy.bullet.y + (player.enemy.offsetHeight / 4) + 'px';
    player.enemy.bulletCount++;
    player.enemy.bulletInterval = false;
    setInterval(function(){
        player.enemy.bulletInterval = true;
    }, 4000);
}

function endGame() {
    if (player.enemy) {
        gameArea.removeChild(player.enemy);
    }
    gameArea.removeChild(player.plane);
    if (player.bomb){
        gameArea.removeChild(player.bomb);
        player.bomb = null;
    }
    score.style.display = 'none';
    scoreArea.style.display = 'none';
    text.style.display = 'none';
    gameMessage.style.display = 'inline-block';
    player.inplay = false;
    player.hasBomb = 0;
    finalScore = document.createElement('div');
    finalScore.classList.add('finalScore');
    finalScore.innerHTML = 'YOU SCORED: ' + Math.floor(player.score);
    gameArea.appendChild(finalScore);
    player.games = 1;
    player.getHit = 0;
}

function removeEnemy() {
    gameArea.removeChild(player.enemy);
    player.enemy = null;
    player.score += 2000;
}
```

Comment: While I applaud you on providing the amount of code you have, personally it reads as a bit disjointed.  I'm unclear how the bottom variable definitions relate to the other methods.  Can you perhaps include a single version that shows the relationship of when in the code the variables are created and when the functions are defined?

Comment: As @Taplar is saying, one method of debugging is to remove code you believe not germane to your problem until you can define the issue in the simplest of terms. Often, by doing so you solve the problem. If not, it's easier to share your question with others.

Comment: @Taplar Okay I provided the full js file. It's not well organized at all. This is actually my first 'on my own' project so forgive me for the headache :(

Comment: @Mugs Don't worry about that.  The concern is more with knowing the code structure.  `let` has special scope rules and depending on if you structure your code in a certain way, the variables could easily not exist when you need them to be.  Seeing the code in it's actual structure allows us to look for these issues.

Comment: i didnt read through all the code but it looks like the if statement in makeBullet is missing curly brackets, therefore when the if statement is false `player.enemy.bullet = document.createElement('div');` is not going to execute but all the other lines are still going to execute.

Comment: @ChrisLi Ah! That worked! Thank you!! Such a small thing caused me so much pain :,(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function makeBullet() {
    if (player.enemy.bulletCount < player.enemy.maxBulletCount && 
player.enemy.bulletInterval == true)
```

youre missing curly braces at the end of the if statement and i think its interpretting the next line as a part single line if statement

change to

```
function makeBullet() {
    if (player.enemy.bulletCount < player.enemy.maxBulletCount && 
player.enemy.bulletInterval == true) {
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```